# Convert from Bytes[32] to bytes32 or bytes8 vyper

Tags: vyper, convert

In vyper, how can I convert:

```py
response: Bytes[32] = raw_call(your_contract_address, call_data, max_outsize=32)
```

to a `bytes32` or even just take the first 8 bytes?

```py
response: bytes8 = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `Bytes[]` to `bytes32` with the [convert](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built-in-functions.html?highlight=convert#convert) method.

```py
response: Bytes[32] = raw_call(your_contract_address, call_data, max_outsize=32)
converted_response: bytes32 = convert(response, bytes32)
```

Or, you can use [extract](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built-in-functions.html#extract32):

```py
converted_response: bytes32 = extract32(response, 0)
```

Then, you can convert your `bytes32` to `bytes8`

```py
extra_converted_response: bytes8 = convert(converted_response, bytes8)
```